# Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'UIDevice'

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Here is my code which was working before.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ImageScrollView.changeOrientationNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove `Notification.Name.` prefix:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ImageScrollView.changeOrientationNotification), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

The constants for notifications names were moved in iOS 12 SDK which came with Xcode 10.

Answer (score 1):

April 9th 2020, I ran into a similar problem. I've got:

```
name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide
```

And I had to "Replace 'UIKeyboardWillHide' with 'UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification'"
I clicked "fix" and got:

```
name: Notification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
```

After that I got "Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'UIResponder'". And finally, Thanks to you guys, I figured out:

```
name: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.
```

Maybe my case and the answer will also help some beginner))